# Python: random numbers list and index

Tags: python, random, indexing

I want to create a sudoku game.

My idea is to generate 9 random lists and that the for loop goes through each individual line and after reading each index, it is compared with the previous line with the same index.

How to use index a[n] == b[n] when I have n lines? a, b, c and etc.

For now, that's all I have below:

Random number generator

```
import random

row = range(1, 10)
print(random.sample(row, k=9))
```

Number compatibility

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 4, 5]


counter = 0
for i in a:
    if i == b[counter]:
        print("the numbers match" + str(i) + str(counter))
    else:
        print("the numbers do not match" + str(i) + str(counter))
    counter += 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean something like `[idx for idx, (element_a, element_b) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if element_a == element_b]`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly your question but does something like this help you :

```
lines = [
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 8],
    [2, 2, 6, 5, 6],
    [1, 4, 6, 5, 7]
]

for n in range(len(lines[0])):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lines):
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(lines):
            if lines[i][n] == lines[j][n]:
               print(f'numbers match in row {i} and {j} at column {n}: {lines[i][n]}')
            j += 1
        i += 1
```